# Textbox Textchanged event

Tags: asp.net

This is with reference to .Net Framework 3.5.

How does a Textbox Server Control raises TextChanged Event through IPostbackdata handler.

Does it uses viewstate internally to store previous value?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A detailed answer to your question is here:
[When TextBox TextChanged event is fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586923/when-textbox-textchanged-event-is-fired)

ViewState is required, see the MSDN [TextBox.TextChanged documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> A TextBox control must persist some values between posts to the server for this event to work correctly. Be sure that view state is enabled for this control.

Comment: That's what i am asking..how does the textbox handles that task of storing previous value since both present and previous value are needed for raising a TextChanged event?.Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Based on the documentation it is clear that it stores the previous value in the ViewState. Something like: `ViewState["previous_value"] = foo.Text`

Comment: So what happens if i disable viewstate for the textbox control?

Comment: see the link I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks justin,now i got the idea.We should enable viewstate for TextXChanged event to work properly.